# Second RDP session on dedicated server

Tags: windows-server-2008, administration

I bought dedicated server by Windows Server 2008 R2. In options, I check "additional IP". I can create two users on my server. How I can connect to them (RDP) at the same time? (using both IP-s?)
//sorry for bad english..

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer that concisely as you haven't said what is and isn't working currently, but I'll try to cover the obvious possibilities. I'm assuming that you're talking about remote admin.

By default Windows Server 2008 R2 (and other versions) doesn't allow RDP connections, you first have to enable it and grant the relevant users permissions to connect. Select Start then right click on Computer and click Properties. In the System window, click Remote settings on the left hand side of the window. In the Remote tab, ensure that one of the two Allow connections... options has been selected, then click Select Users and add the two users you've created.

By default I believe RDP on the server is configured to listen on all connections on the server, but you can check that by running tsconfig.msc, then in the Connections section right click on RDP-Tcp and select Properties. Go into the Network Adaptor tab and check what is selected, by default this should be "All network adaptors configured with this protocol".

The fact that you've configured the server with two IP addresses (I'm assuming on the same NIC from your description) shouldn't make a difference, the two users should be able to connect via RDP using either using one or both of them.